# Check if string contain an array of keyword

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, keyword

I don't find what I need on internet, or may be I don't use correct words, but here is my problem.

I have a string for exemple:
Ok bot, show me the doc of the Foo program.

And there is my keywords: `["bot","doc", "show", "Foo"]`

I want that if the string contains 3 keyword or more, my function will return a message for exemple

I have think about

```js
var message = "Ok bot, show me the doc of the Foo program.";
var keywords = ["bot","doc","show","foo"];
if(keywords.indexOf(message) >=3 ){
  console.log('ok I understand');
}
```

But it not works

Can someone help me please ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the `indexOf` function, which returns the items index in the array. In your case you are checking `message` in the array keywords which is logically wrong condition

You can filter the found keywords via [**Array#filter**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [**String#includes**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) and then check their length.

```js
var message = "Ok bot, show me the doc of the Foo program.";
var keywords = ["bot","doc","show","foo"];

var keywordsFound = keywords.filter(item => message.includes(item));

if(keywordsFound.length >= 3 ) {
  console.log('ok I understand');
}
```

Comment: you should edit your includes link to be this one: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes

Comment: @MikeCheel Thanks